# Why my function is looping until Prolog crashes

Tags: recursion, prolog

I can't seem to understand why my function is looping until Prolog crashes:

```erlang
isTerminalRow(_,_,_,Count,10):-
    Count > 4.

isTerminalRow(B,A,Index,Count,Move):-
    checkValue(B,Index,A,V),
    C2 is V + Count,
    I2 is Index + 1,
    Move1 is Move + 1,
    isTerminalRow(B,A,I2,C2,Move1).

checkValue(B,Index,A,V):- 
    getE(Index,B,Value), 
    Value = A, V is 1
  ; V is 0. 

getE(1,[H|_],H).    % get nth element 
getE(I,[_|T],L):- 
    I1 is I - 1, 
    getE(I1,T,L).
```

The call is

```
?-  isTerminalRow([w,w,w,w,w,e,e,e,e,e],w,1,0,10).
```

Comment: ([list] , 'charachter', counter of charachter ocurrence in list,limted moves)
as for chechvalue it returns number 1 at V if the charachter at list is equal to the charachter A and 0 if not.

Comment: sorry this is my first time to ask on this site 
this is an example isTerminalRow([w,w,w,w,w,r,r,r,r,r,r],1,0,1).

Comment: Please show the definition of `checkValue/4`. It impacts the value of the counter that `isTerminalRow/5` uses as criteria for termination.

Comment: @lurker if `Move` is not 10, it doesn't even get a chance to consider the termination.

Comment: @WillNess `Move` starts at 1 and is incremented by 1 on each recursive call to `isTerminalRow/5`. Won't it reach 10 after 9 iterations? Of course, it must do so when the count exceeds 4. if it does so sooner, then it will loop.

Comment: @lurker probably the input list gets exhausted, and `V` becomes 0 from that point on.

Comment: @WillNess probably, or maybe. We don't know without knowing what `checkValue/4` is doing.

Comment: Hold up.... `isTerminalRow([w,w,w,w,w,r,r,r,r,r,r],1,0,1).` isn't a valid call. It's missing an argument.

Comment: @lurker the termination conditions are just too specific and too easily missed, after which point there's no chance to stop.

Comment: @WillNess I agree that it is oddly specific.Youssef, please edit your question and add the code there. Do not post code in comments. It's hard to read, and it doesn't easily benefit others who read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `is` uses, `Move` and `Count` are ground when you call `isTerminalRow`. For your first clause to fire, when `Count` becomes larger than 4, `Move` must be 10.

If not, the first clause does not fire; it doesn't even get a chance to consider the value of `Count`, and the execution continues with the second clause, which just loops (if `checkValue/4` doesn't fail, that is).

Your termination conditions are too specific. Chances are, they are never met.

*update:* from your comments, `Move` is already 10 in your query, and `Count` is 0, so the first clause fails. After that, `Move` is always greater than 10 because you increment it with `Move1 is Move + 1`, and there's no chance for `Count > 4` to even be tested, ever.

Comment: dosn't prolog try to match ever time and I made move to increase every ti me ?
and I mad a mistake this is a better representation of the function 
 isTerminalRow([w,w,w,w,w,e,e,e,e,e],w,1,0,10).
as you can see I want know if the w occured for 5 or more times

Comment: we don't know what your checkValue is doing. but when Move hits 10, and Count is not greater than 4, the execution will continue and Move will never be 10 again after that, so it won't ever terminate.

Comment: ... because Move will be matched for equality with 10 ***before*** even trying to compare Count  with 4.

Comment: checkValue(B,Index,A,V):-
 getE(Index,B,Value),
 Value = A,V is 1;
 V is 0.
this is what check value does
and for the function getE it looks like this 
getE(1,[H|_],H).  %get nth element
getE(I,[_|T],L):-
 I1 is I - 1,
 getE(I1,T,L).

Comment: @YoussefGabr if `V` comes back 0 enough times, then `Move` will reach 10 before `Count` exceeds 4 and then you will never terminate.

Comment: @lurker scratch my previous comment, `Move` is already 10 in the *initial call* !

Comment: @YoussefGabr great. you can now accept the answer, to mark the issue resolved. (it also gives you +2 reputation).